# Limit on number of subscriptions per azure account?

Tags: azure, limit, subscriptions

I know that we can create multiple subscriptions per azure account. Is there any limit on the number of subscriptions in single windows azure account ?

Comment: This is a billing question, not a programming question. You should send a question to Azure billing support.

Answer (score 1):

Not that I'm aware of.  I don't see anything at http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsazure/hh531793.aspx which would suggest a limit.

Answer (score 0):

There is a limit right now (2019-04-16):
One Account - 50 Subscription, after opening a support case they could increase up to 200.
**BUT THIS APPLY ONLY FOR Powershell / CLI / REST.**

There is no limit through management portal.